# What is the difference between Domain model and Design model?

Tags: java, uml

I'm creating a design model through the domain model. I'm not getting what is the difference between design model and domain model. We just have to add attributes and methods to domain model? How do I create design model through domain model?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "creating a design model through the domain model?"

Answer (score 0):

The Domain "model" is just a part of the total design, it is concerned with the problem domain and attempts to create a useful working model of the domain in which you are creating a solution for (note this doesn't have to model the domain exactly).  It typically/ideally is isolated from the "solution design"  which is what technology frameworks, databases, UI etc you are using to get working software

Comment: So there are exact classes and relationships in domain and design? And we have to add UI, frameworks etc. to doamin model to make it design model?

Comment: you have this notion of "design model" which doesn't really exist.  I think you mean your actual implementation,  however, its not that useful in relation to a domain model.   a domain model is realized in code ( ie, your implementation and domain model can be the same thing) .  However, typically, the code related to the domain model is isolated from the rest of the system.  Often on the internet, a lot of the discussion around DDD is to do with how to isolate your domain model from the rest of your system and the patterns that help that.

Comment: and domain modelling, how to derive your domain model, is a interactive human process of finding the right words (ubiquitous language), questioning the domain experts and exploring the "moving parts" of the system and how they interrelate and what you "name" those things

Answer (score 0):

Domain model is a business model. It does not depend on software system.
Design model is a model of software system.

Example.
Domain - Bookkeeping. Domain model element - account, credit, etc

Design - Bookkeeper system. Design model element - database, GUI, etc

It is Okey, if some elements from domain model will appear in design model, for example, account (from domain model) can become the account table in database schema (design model).